# Как послать POST запрос на сервис с JSF страницы?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, веб-сервер, jsf

Пишу проект на `JavaEE(Jsf2+)`.Стоит задача подключиться к удаленному веб-сервису который будет на запрос выдавать `JSON` ответ. Какие способы обращения есть через `JSF` к удаленному веб-сервису.Мне на голову приходит только `HttpUrlConnection`.Но есть ли какие-то другие пути? Более правильные ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [JAX-RS](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339):

```
SomeEntity entity = client
                      .target("http://example.com/some-rest-service/entities")
                      .path("42")
                      .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                      .get(SomeEntity.class);
```